# how to post data to this function file_get_contents("php://input") to read a file from the server

Tags: php, html, forms, input, file-get-contents

I need to create html page to send data to file.php which contains this code:
file_get_contents("php://input");
to make it show a file from the server...

can this be done??

Comment: This is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/): [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

to get output from a file you dont need to use php:// wrapper. you can get the files locally(preffered) or over http://

check the manual http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: I know how to use file_get_contents , you didn't answer my question ..  so what do you think you did

Comment: I dont know mind reading. From your post it seems you dont know or you have not asked the question correctly. I was trying to help you, you dont need to be rude for that.

Comment: didn't mean to be rude ... But needed to make a declaration here .. :)